# How to return two objects in one method without using pair?

Tags: java

I want to return `m` and `n` but `return (m, n)` won't work. Is there any way I can `return` the two values? 
I am not suppose to use `Pair` as I have not been taught about it yet.

```
public static void getTwoIntegers(MyInteger m, MyInteger n)
{
     Random rand = new Random();

     m = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
     n = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return in an `array`,

```
public static MyInteger[] getTwoIntegers(){
   Random rand = new Random();
   MyInteger m = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
   MyInteger n = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
   return new MyInteger[] {m,n};
}
```

Comment: I guess, `m` and `n` should't be parameters of the method, `getTwoIntegers() {...} ` would  be efficient.

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo - Yep thats right. We don't need that If we are returning it in an array. Thanks, I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I wrote any java code, but can't you just use an array?

Or use some wrapper-object (you are allowed to use objects, rights?) like `new SomeClass(m, n)`

#### upd

Array:

```
public static MyInteger[] getTwoIntegers(MyInteger m, MyInteger n)
{
     Random rand = new Random();

     m = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
     n = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
     MyInteger[] result = {m, n};
     return result;
}
```

#### upd2

Object:

```
public static MyIntegerPair getTwoIntegers(MyInteger m, MyInteger n)
{
     Random rand = new Random();

     m = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
     n = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
     return new MyIntegerPair(m, n);
}

public class MyIntegerPair {
    public MyInteger first;
    public MyInteger second;
    public MyIntegerPair(f, s) {
        this.first = f;
        this.second = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: good, but you used `void` in the method signature, and then you use `return`

Comment: Yeah, I just copypasted code from question:) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another concept besides returning a value.

```
public static void getTwoIntegers(List<MyInteger> ret)
{
     Random rand = new Random();

     MyInteger m = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
     MyInteger n = new MyInteger(rand.nextInt(10));
     ret.add(m);
     ret.add(n);
}
```

Now getting 3 or 4 integers is just as simple.